# Ошибка Broken pipe в PyMySql | Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, mysql, база-данных, pymysql

Всем привет! Столкнулся с проблемой с `pymysql`. У меня есть функция для считывания определенных данных по REST-API и после записи их в БД, и это нужно выполнять по определенному расписанию. Я использую для запуска кода по расписанию такую штуку:

```
import schedule

def job():
    # Тут функция, которая будет выполняться по расписанию

schedule.every().day.at("09:00").do(job) #Каждый день в 09:00 запускать job()

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Проблема как я понял в `pymysql`, который видимо за время ожидания теряет коннект с сервером. Подключение `pymysql` у меня в отдельном файле, код такой (заменил данные на #):

```
import pymysql

connection = pymysql.connect(host='###.###.###.###',
                             user='####',
                             password='########',
                             database='####',
                             charset='utf8mb4',
                             cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
```

Залил на сервер и открыл с помощью утилиты `Screen` сессию, в которой запустил мой файл с функцией

В 09:00 срабатывает, но пишет ошибку "broken pipe", которая вроде означает, что время сессии истекло. Можно как-то убрать ограничение на время сессии или заставить `pymysql` переподключаться к серверу в случае ошибки, которую можно отловить try/except? Или просто выполнять `pymysql.connect` непосредственно в `job()`?

Answer (score 0):

В общем, просто pymysql.connect в job() выполняю, других способов, что-то вроде pymysql.reconnect() не нашел